# Typo3 error message at Flexible Content - Download Links

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

what does this error message mean in backend:

*Ordner mit Dateien zum Download (geschützte Dateien müssen in einem Unterordner 'protected' sein!)*

I moved the original to my development and the pictures are now not showing in frontend.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here are images from Backend:

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need a lot of more information. Please attach code of the flexible content and a screenshot and/or the location of this message. The backend is big, so there should be more details.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler I have added backend images. I hope that helps a bit. Thank you!

Comment: This is no error message, this is a label for a field.

Comment: You can see the error message on the first image. Second image is the "element" i used.

Comment: I repeat: This is not an error message. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a label of a field which is displayed in the page view. There is no error message.